# RSS Reader and parser using java

Tags: java, rss, xmlpullparser, rss-reader, rome

I need to implement the RSS reader kind of using Java.

I have designed the Java class which reads the RSS feed XML URL and get the contents and store it in Java class.

Whenever there is an update in RSS feel URL, i need to parse the RSS feed XML URL using Java class, only then i could get the updated contents.

The problem here is how we notify the Java class that RSS feel XML URL has been updated, so that Java class could parse the URL and get the updated contents?

Do we have to implement thread to run the parsing process continously? or any alternative optimal solutions there?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cron job that runs the java application to parse the rss feed. It depends on the frequency the RSS feed is going to get updated. You could implement a polling solution here if the information in the RSS feed is updated frequently. This would involve setting up a thread that sleeps for a certain amount of time, then recalls the parse method.